# check if email exists in mongodb while typing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

this project uses `js` , `mongoose` , `node.js`
if use an email that already exists during registration to create an account, it will refresh the page clear all fields and shows a pop up message using ajax that says email exists. i dont want the fields to be cleared

im trying to fix this. the idea that i thought would be perfect is if i can use an event listener that will check the email against the database every time the user types something in the email input field. i already did this with `js` to make sure the passwords are identical before posting,  all help and tips and remarks are welcome

here is the part of the code that checks if email exists

```
module.exports.signUp = async (req, res) => {
  const { site_web, username, fonction, direction, email} = req.body

  try {
        if(email){
          var check = await InscritModel.findOne({ email: email });
          if(check){
            res.render('inscription', { layout: 'inscription', email: true});
          }
           else{
                 // create user
               }
      }

  }
  
}
```

***UPDATE***
im still stuck with this, i trying to use ajax to constantly check the email input against the database in real time, but i know im messing up a lot of things,
i created a post route in `user-routes` called `router.post("/emailCheck", emailCheck);` and in function-controller file i created this function

```
module.exports.emailCheck = async (email) => {
  
  var check = await InscritModel.findOne({ email: email });
  if(check){
   return 1;
  }
   else{
     return 0;}
}
```

this is the html input call

```
 <input type="email" id="txtUserEmail" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email.." required>
```

and this is the crazy ajax code

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtUserEmail').keyup(function () {
        var email = $(this).val();
        if (email.length >= 3) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/emailCheck',
                method: 'post',
                data: { email: email },
                success: function (data) {
                    var divElement = $('#divOutput');
                    if (data) {
                        divElement.text(' already in use');
                        divElement.css('color', 'red');
                    }
                    else {
                        divElement.text( ' available')
                        divElement.css('color', 'green');
                    }
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

its shows a  one very long error message with so many things, it ends with this

```
 Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 8)
```

hopefuly ill get there, any help is appreciated, the idea i have in mind is to make ajax call a function that takes an email in its parameters and checks it against the database and returns true or false.

Answer (score 0):

well, i ended up finding the solution, ill share for future people.

**the goal:** stop the other fields from getting cleared when the email already exists in database

**the problem:** verifying the email happens after the form is submit, which means the page gets refreshed

**solution idea:** disable the submit button, use js to listen on the email input, and verify the input against the database while the user is typing.

***app.js or routes.js whatever u named it***

```
const InscritModel = require('../models/inscrit-model');

router.get('/usercheck', function(req, res) {
  
  console.log(req.query);
// dont forget to import the user model and change InscritModel by whatever you used
   InscritModel.findOne({email: req.query.email}  , function(err, InscritModel){
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      var message;
      if(InscritModel) {
        console.log(InscritModel)
          message = "user exists";
          console.log(message)
      } else {
          message= "user doesn't exist";
          console.log(message)
      }
      res.json({message: message});
  });
});
```

**in html**

```
<div id="divOutput"></div>
<input type="email" id="usercheck" required>
<input type="submit" id="btsubmit"  disabled />
```

**in JS**

```
$('#usercheck').on('keyup', function () {
  console.log("ok");
  console.log($(this).val().toLowerCase());
  $.get('/usercheck?email=' + $(this).val().toLowerCase(), function (response) {
    $('#divOutput').text(response.message);
    var bouton = document.getElementById('btsubmit');
    bouton.disabled = true;
  

    if ($('#divOutput').html() === "user exists") {
      $('#divOutput').text('Email not available').css('color', 'red');
    }
    else {
      $('#divOutput').text('Email available').css('color', 'green');
        bouton.disabled = false;
      
    }
  })
});
```